# WSO2 ESB CACHE: return same responses for different SOAP request with same URL endpont

Tags: caching, wso2, esb

I speack spanihs. Will try english.
I have a WSO2 proxy service for a backend SOAP WebService. It works fine!
The problem starts when i enable Response Caching for the proxy service, 20 seconds caching.
I set ports in TCPMonitor(localhost 8280 and the one for backend service).
I see that when i send different requests to the proxy, it returns same cached response. It return the response cached for the first request into that 20 seconds of life into the cache.

Differents body http for different requests, but same headers and POST URI.

Does ESB do the hash with headers+body or only the headers?

Thansk for your help
Diego

Answer (score 0):

Are you suing [cache mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Cache+Mediator)?
cache mediator caches the response, whenevr it sees same request comes to the system, it sends back the cached response.
Or else did you enable the [response caching](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Response+Caching) fro proxy services?

Comment: Hello! thanks. I just enabled the repsonse caching for the proxy service. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Response aching happens like this;  it caches the responses for requests that are identical, thereby enhancing the response time for subsequent requests. That means if you send same request only , you will be getting the cached rseponse, if it is different request, you should get a different response..if  you get same response for all requests within the caching period it is a bug:(

Comment: Ups.. bug.. :( first, I send a request with just only one searchching parameter value, and next time i send anothers with 2 parameter values, and other different webService operations. This means different SOAP request messages, and the same responses(saw it at TCPMONITOR). ESB 4.6.0

Comment: I put a logger at the inSequence of the proxy like this:
<log>
<property name="axis2_VALOR_REQUEST_HASH" expression="$axis2:requestHash"/>
</log>

I got same request_hush for different request:
<br/>
[2013-05-14 16:23:19,668]  INFO - LogMediator To:  
axis2_VALOR_REQUEST_HASH = -18-126-33-100-36-93-51-11612-104115-11063-30-54123
<br/>
[2013-05-14 16:24:33,770]  INFO - LogMediator To:
axis2_VALOR_REQUEST_HASH = -18-126-33-100-36-93-51-11612-104115-11063-30-54123

Comment: Ok...
It returns me ever the same request_hash value for all soap requests, as a constant:
axis2_VALOR_REQUEST_HASH = -18-126-33-100-36-93-51-11612-104115-11063-30-54123

Comment: so a bug..monitor the jira for the update https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14107